# Is it possible to exclude specific SSIDs from the wifi network finder?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

I work in an office hotel situated above a bunch of cafés, as such there are a ton of different wireless networks. Sometimes I can't even see the network I want to connect to on the list of available networks.

Is there any way of telling OS X that I never want to be shown certain SSIDs?
I'd love to be able to have a list to ignore but I can't seem to find any way to do this.

*(Note that this has **nothing** to do with `Preferred Networks`. All the anwers to similar questions I've seen have been about people not knowing that they've accidentally added the wrong WiFi to preferred networks. This is not about that. This is about filtering the actual list of available networks because there are too many of them)*

Comment: Your machine should automatically reconnect to your network on wake/boot. If you keep having to go into the Wi-Fi menu so often that the long list is annoying, it makes me think auto-join is broken for you, and that's what needs to get fixed first.

Comment: The wifi-situation is indeed "broken" in that I have to switch networks in order to perform certain tasks. There are also some networks that go down intermittantly. However that is beyond my control and my computer is within my control, thus I would like to be able to quickly pick one of the appropriate networks and see which of them are up. I find it pretty annoying that the only solution seems to be "fix your infrastructure" when being able to blacklist SSIDs seems like such a simple feature.

Comment: @Liminal , did you find solution for this?